# Create a new column in Pandas Dataframe based on the 'NaN' values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

What is the most efficient way to create a new column based off of nan values in a separate column (considering the dataframe is very large)
In OTW, If any column has a `NaN` in one of the rows, the corresponding value of the new column should be `1`

> Note: The dtypes of the column may be different objects, not just integers/floats

```
X A   B
1 2   3    
4 NaN 1    
7 8   9    
3 2   NaN  
5 NaN 2
```

Should give

```
X A   B    C
1 2   3    0
4 NaN 1    1
7 8   9    0
3 2   NaN  1
5 NaN 2    1
```

Code Tried (Thanks to some online help):

```
df['C'] = np.where(np.any(np.isnan(df[['A', 'B']])), 1, 0)
```

but it throws the following error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

And this returns an empty dataframe (Since both A and B columns never have NaN values in a single row

```
df['C'] = np.where(np.any(pd.isnull(df[['A', 'B']])), 1, 0)
```

> Found a Workaround :

```
df['C1'] = np.where(np.isnan(df['A'].values), 1, 0) 
df['C2'] = np.where(np.isnan(df['B'].values), 1, 0)
df['C'] = df[['C1','C2']].max(axis=1)
```

You may then drop `C1` and `C2`

Hope this helps~

Comment: tried that, returns an empty dataframe. I think it uses the AND operator in the above snippet where it should be using OR

Comment: You do not have columns A and B in your df

Comment: please check new edits @WeNYoBen

Comment: What are the dtypes?

Comment: In my current use case, datetime

Comment: I think its a bad workaround solution. and I think you need max instead of min function.

Comment: You're correct. Actually in my code, if there's NOT a NaN, then output zero; hence the minimum. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll make the edits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simple than you think. Hope this may Help you!

```
df['C'] = df.isna().sum(axis=1).apply(lambda x: 0 if x==0 else 1)
```

Comment: how do I specify columns with this snippet ? I only want to check in specific columns

Comment: you can use df[['A','B','C']].isna().sum(axis=1).apply(lambda x: 0 if x==0 else 1)

Comment: you mean `df['C'] = df[['A','B']].isna().sum(axis=1).apply(lambda x: 0 if x==0 else 1)` ? That doesn't work, returns an empty df

Comment: Please check all related code. its runs successfully. link for reference https://paste.pics/be8af44c7f5f3afdc37a23e9dd32e192

Comment: Updated the question. The dtypes of A and B need not be integers. Could be objects like datetime

Comment: It will work too. this code does not consider datatype. may be you can give some more information about problem statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203074/discussion-between-girish-kuniyal-and-jokol).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `axis=1` in `any`

```
np.where(np.any(np.isnan(df[['A', 'B']]),axis=1), 1, 0)
Out[80]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1])
```

Comment: `np.isnan` still gives the type error mentioned in the question